# NodeJS cannot find module

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

I have entities directory that store user.js file like this:

```
"use strict";

class User {}

module.exports = User;
```

and in my index.js:

```
var User = require("./entities/User")
```

but I got an error

> Error: Cannot find module './entities/User'
>       at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
>       at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
>       at Socket.socket.on (/home/etours/capstone-etours/index.js:154:21)
>       at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
>       at Socket.emit (events.js:194:7)
>       at /home/etours/capstone-etours/node_modules/socket.io/lib/socket.js:503:12
>       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)

Comment: try replacing `User = require("./entities/User")` with `User = require("./entities/user")` because its based off of file name

Comment: Check your file name. The require statement is looking for exports in a file.

Answer (score 0):

The require function it's case sensitive so you have to write the path exactly how you created.

if you use the `U` lowercase it's gonna work :D

Answer (score 0):

You should try this code:

**user.js**

```
var User = function() {};
module.exports = User;

var User = class User {   
};

module.exports.User = User;
```

**index.js**

```
var User = require("./user");
console.log(User);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try below code:

**user.js:**

```
var User={};
module.exports = User;

var User = class User {    
};

module.exports.User = User;
```

**index.js:**

```
var User = require("./user");
console.log(User);
```